# What data structure for this operation?

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

Say I have two arrays, `energy (E) and score (S)`, and they could have elements like this:

```
E = {1 , 3 , 4, 7};
S = {16, 10, 5, 1};
```

What I want is the best score with the best energy. What data structure can support inserting items in a way that I don't have have an item with less energy and less score than another item `i.e. for any i,j where i!=j => score[i] > score[j] || energy[i] > energy[j]`

When inserting, I do three steps:

1- if any item has more or equal score and energy, return;

2- if any item has less or equal score and energy, remove this item;

3- insert the required item.

Here are some examples:
1- insert e=8, s=1. The arrays become:

```
E = {1 , 3 , 4, 8};
S = {16, 10, 5, 1};
                ^
```

2- insert `e=5`, `s=6`. The arrays becomes:

```
E = {1 , 3 , 5, 8};
S = {16, 10, 6, 1};
             ^
```

3- insert e=5, s=11. The arrays becomes :

```
E = {1 , 5 , 8};
S = {16, 11, 1};
         ^    (3,10) is removed because (5,11) has more energy and more score than it.
```

What data structure can support this in (hopefully) O(logn) time?

Comment: Well a table in a relational database could support this. Is that what you're after? It's a very broad question.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but it seems more like a question suited for http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/ instead of SO.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid, I want to implement this data structure using my language of choice (C#), so I don't know how relational database tables can help here. If you could elaborate more,I'd be grateful.

Comment: @Enigmativity I really think cstheory is not a good site to ask this. This place is very much about research-grade questions (and i don't think this qualifies yet).

Comment: Well a database stores the information permanently. A C# structure doens't - its in memory. Anyway once you sort out your C# structure you can probably use LINQ after the fact to store it in a database if you like. Really I'm just illustrating how broad your question is - you might want to edit it and the tags to narrow it down to a C# structure

Comment: If O(logn) is possible (what i think), then it's just in amortized manner, because one adding can result in deleting all N items already part of the data-structure. (at least without some assumptions about you query-statistics)

Comment: @AymanElTemsahi - I suggest that you add the [C#] tag and present your data as valid C# code.

Comment: [Also posted on CS.SE](http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/62785/755), where you can find an answer.
Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

My solution to this problem is to use a `max-heap` that stores a `pair` structure as the value of its nodes. If you're not familiar with heaps, the [CLRS book, chapter 6](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0262033844) has the best discussion I've read of them.

The `max-heapfiy` method of a heap bubbles up the max to the top, such that any particular node's children all have lower value than their parent. You can use this property as a condition for removing subnodes and maintaining the heap property. In your case, it sounds like you may be deleting entire subtrees when both energy and score of the inserted node are greater than a particular child, and only deleting a single node when either energy or score is greater.

Comment: While i think the max-heap is a good start, can you clarify a bit on the details of handling these pair-structures. I would have thought, that the order-function has to obey some rules like **transitivity** (which might be a problem with the ordering-definition above because of the OR). Nonetheless, i think a max-heap-based approach (using 2 of these; where internal-swappings are recorded) could be the core of an efficient solution.

Comment: In the requirements, "less or equal score and energy" is a little ambiguous. If a solution looks at `score` and `energy` as two parameters of a `comparator()` then you get something like this:

    int comparator(pair p, pair q) {
        if (p.energy > q.energy && p.score > q.score) {
            return 1;
        } else if (p.energy == q.energy && p.score == q.score) {
            return 0;
        }
        return -1;
    }

The end result is that neither `energy` or `score` are on top but the pair of them is ordered according to the requirements.

Comment: It's obvious how to implement this order-relation. But is it following the rules, which are probably: ```needs strict weak-ordering``` ( transitive + irreflexive)?

Comment: @sascha Thanks for pointing that out, I'm reading up on `strict weak-ordering` right now to familiarize myself with it...

Comment: What do you think about **antisymmetry**: ```For all x, y in S, if x < y then it is not the case that y < x (asymmetry).```. Let's take A: e 5 s 3, B: e 2 s 4 -> then according to OP's ```i,j where i!=j => score[i] > score[j] || energy[i] > energy[j]``` both are true: A < B (score), and B < A (energy) which would break it. Do you approve? I only mentioned **strict weak-ordering** because it's the basic-assumption in many libraries (most important: C++'s STL). I don't know, if it's necessary for the *max-heap*, but i believe so. @AndrewC.

Comment: I don't think this proposed approach works. How exactly do you propose to remove subnodes?  When we insert a new pair (s,e), how do we find out whether there's some other pair already in the heap that dominates it, without searching every element in the heap?  I don't think that's possible -- I don't think a heap data structure lets you do that.  In other words, I think this answer is wrong.   Since you don't spell out a precise algorithm (for how to 'this property as a condition for removing subnodes'), I can't give a more concrete counterexample.  Instead, see CS.SE for a correct answer.

Comment: @sascha This case, order of insertion matters. Start with heap of one node, A { e=5 s=3 }, then insert B { e=2 s=4 }. B is rejected because neither B.e or B.s are greater than A's. Now consider one-node heap containing B, inserting A would make A the root and B child. If I understand what you are asking, order of insertion like this case is improper to maintaining a heap. You are indeed correct and I approve of your comment. Since the requirements reject insertion depending on state of the structure, antisymmetry must be allowed, which makes this structure "heap-like" and not strictly a heap.